# Spotipy not changing users

Tags: python, django, spotipy

So I am making a Spotify statistics app which just shows some stats about the user's Spotify account using the Django and the Spotipy python module. I made the user's first name a required field and labeled it Spotify Username so that the user enters their Spotify username and it is stored in the users table as the first_name (I realize the flaws with this approach, I am just trying to get everything up and running). My problem is that no matter how many times I logout and switch users, the responses from the Spotify api don't change. Take for example this function:

```
@login_required
def recents(request):
    token = spotipy.util.prompt_for_user_token(
        username=request.user.first_name, scope=SCOPE, client_id=CLIENT_ID, client_secret=CLIENT_SECRET, redirect_uri=REDIRECT_URI)

    session = spotipy.Spotify(auth=token)
    recents = session.current_user_recently_played(limit=8)
    recents = recents["items"]
    return render(request, 'stats/recents.html', {
        "recents": recents
    })
```

I specify `username=request.user.first_name` but the recents page for every user shows the recent songs on my own Spotify account. I have a hunch that this is because my `REDIRECT_URI` is `http://localhost:8080/` so it is automatically signing into my own account, however I'm not sure.

Answer (score 0):

You have to add `show_dialog=True` inside the `prompt_for_user_token()` as you can see [here](https://github.com/plamere/spotipy/blob/master/examples/multiple_accounts.py).